# PostGIS uuid type not visible in QGIS or GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, qgis

This is probably a simple question, but nothing comes to my mind right now.

I have created a *view* in PostGIS containing multiple columns, including one column of data type `uuid`.

When I try to visualize the view as a layer in either *QGIS* or *GeoServer* the column of data type `uuid` is simply omitted while the rest of the columns looks fine.

**Is the data type uuid not supported by neither QGIS or GeoServer or is it a simple mistake on my part?**

Versions:

- QGIS: 1.7
- PostGIS: 1.5.2
- PostgreSQL: 9.0.1
- GeoServer: 2.0.2

Comment: I don't think it is supported yet in QGIS or GeoServer - A few QGIS developers might advise otherwise.

Comment: Have you considered using OIDs instead of UUIDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers) are not supported in QGIS yet. For now, it seems easiest to cast them to text in your view definition.

Comment: Yeah, that is also the alternative I am using for now :)

Answer (score -1):

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/62
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/952

Comment: Yeah, I saw the two, but I prefer to hear user-experience instead of going trough the tickets :)

Comment: Welcome to GIS.StackExchange!  Because we value stand-alone answers that will last over time, could you please explain what is in these links?  (For more tips on answering questions, please read our [FAQ](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq).)